# Language forum to practice German Pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, resource

I would like to find some system which helps my German pronunciation. 
Sometimes, I am long times speaking the language, weakening my fluency. 
I heard that some language laboratories in Asia have capabilities of giving the user instant feedback when speaking to microphone. 
Given a picture about the amplitude of the sound and comparing it instantly with native speaker's pronunciation.

How can you improve your German pronunciation in language forums/systems?

Comment: I think the core question (your last sentence) is too broad, since _systems_ is not well defined and _forums_ is too universal a concept. I'm afraid for improving pronounciation, the only effective way is to actually use the language with natives.

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend Rosetta Stone.

Even though it is not free, it does provide a fairly detailled pronounciation training with detailled graphs, practice sessions, etc.

Though I am using it for Japanese, my wife has been using it to learn German with decent success.

A free apporach with more community involved, would be memrise. There is a detailed course for German from basic to advanced as well as some additional courses... There is a Premium Option, though I have been using it for free with great success and only minor limitations.